# Ruamel yaml import does not work

Tags: python, python-import, ruamel.yaml, liclipse

I want to use Ruamel YAML in my project, I am behind a proxy so I downloaded

The gzip package from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml and installed it with
`pip install ruamel.yaml-0.15.19.tar.gz`.

I use LiClipse on Windows 10 and I see the ruamel package inside my project explorer under lib/site-packages/ruamel, but I cannot import and use it.

It cannot resolve the import.

Other frameworks like paho MQTT or pySerial worked without problems.

Output of `pip list --format-columns`

```
Package     Version
----------- -------
paho-mqtt   1.1
pip         9.0.1
pyserial    3.3
ruamel.yaml 0.15.19
setuptools  28.8.0
```

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with the error message?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I edited the picture to include the 'unresolved import' message.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on a clean install of Python3.6.2 under Windows 7. 1. What I find strange is that you have easy_install in your site-packages, which version of setuptools are your running? (Best to paste into the question the output from `pip list --format columns`, **no screenshots**, cut and paste the text)

Comment: My LiClipse and Python36 installation are also just a month old. And I did nothing special outside of adjusting the interpreter path inside the project settings.

Comment: Did you install something with easy_install? I don't get the 'easy-install.pth' file in my setup, and I cannot install paho-mqtt because of errors.

Comment: Not that I am aware of and I do not really know what easy_install is, to install paho and pySerial I downloaded the packages from the respective homepages and used `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149815/discussion-between-anthon-and-splitframe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked through the source of PyDev 5.8.0 ( LiClipse seem closed source, but the pydev stuff—that I assume handles all the Python related stuff—is open source).

In there, there is in `pydevd.py` has module `get_fullname()` and that correctly finds `ruamel.yaml` if installed:

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 14:33:45) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkgutil
>>> loader = pkgutil.get_loader('ruamel.yaml')
>>> def get_fullname(self, mod_name):
...     if IS_PY3K:
...         import pkgutil
...     else:
...         from _pydev_imps import _pydev_pkgutil_old as pkgutil
...     try:
...         loader = pkgutil.get_loader(mod_name)
...     except:
...         return None
...     if loader is not None:
...         for attr in ("get_filename", "_get_filename"):
...             meth = getattr(loader, attr, None)
...             if meth is not None:
...                 return meth(mod_name)
...     return None
... 
>>> IS_PY3K=True
>>> get_fullname(None, 'ruamel.yaml')
'/home/venv/tmp-d2e4bd3600c863b7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/__init__.py'
```

(since `self` is not referenced this should probably be removed and decorated `@staticmethod`).

I searched the sources for `Unresolved import` and `Unused import` to see if there is some other similar functionality, but could not directly find anything. Since **the import will work, even when this message shows**, it does however look like there is some other (incompatible) way LiClipse uses to look for imports as well.

`ruamel.yaml` is a namespace based package (i.e. there are 200+ other packages that start with `ruamel.`, some of which are on PyPI as well) and this can cause problems. That is also the reason why you have to use `pip` to install.

I have sent a issue report per email to Fabio Zadrozny (the author) about this and offered my assistance to help look into this.

Comment: You are the real MVP